# Bayesian Neural Network: Computation of Hessian

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, mnist, hessian-matrix

I'm trying to code in Python several types of ANN algorithms in order to get a better understanding/intuition of those. I'm not using Scikit-learn or any other ready-to-go packages since my goal is rather educational than practical.
As an example problem, I use MNIST database (http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/).

While I performed simple 1-hidden layer NN and convolutional NN, I successfully avoided any second-order methods of optimization and, thus, didn't compute Hessian matrix. However, then I got to Bayesian NN where, in order to optimize hyperparameters, a computation of Hessian is compulsatory.

In my fully connected network, there are 784 inputs, 300 hidden units, and 10 output units. All of those result in 238200 weights (+ biases).
When I try to compute or even approximate Hessian (by outer product of gradients), Python notifies on "MemoryError". Even if I decrease the number of weights to ~40000 and no error message is displayed, my computer gets stuck after several minutes. As I understand, the problem is that the desirable matrix is extremely huge.
I looked through a couple of articles on Bayesian NNs and noticed that authors usually use network architectures of no more than 10 or 20 inputs and hidden units, thus having a lot fewer parameters than I have. However, I have not seen any explicit statements of such restrictions.

What can I do in order to apply Bayesian approach to NN for MNIST?

More generally: 
Is it possible to apply Bayesian approach with this (238200 weights) or even larger architecture?
Or maybe it is suitable just for relatively small networks?

Answer (score 2):

You could try [the BFGS algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broyden%E2%80%93Fletcher%E2%80%93Goldfarb%E2%80%93Shanno_algorithm) for gradient ascent, which approximates the Hessian and tends to save (considerable) memory.  There's an [implementation in Scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs.html).

Comment: I guess you are thinking about L-BFGS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limited-memory_BFGS), BFGS requires the same amount of memory as the typical hessian methods so if the OPs problem lies in memory consumption - BFGS will fail too

Comment: Yup. Thanks for the clarification.